# Including "Boolean-parser" library in my project ("require is not defined")

Tags: javascript

I would like to use [this library](https://github.com/riichard/boolean-parser-js) (https://github.com/riichard/boolean-parser-js) (which is really just a function?) in my own project.

My project is contained in a single html file. In one of the functions, I've tried including the following:

```
var parser = require('boolean-parser');
```

I get the following error when I include this.

*Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined*

I have installed the library via the terminal, using "npm install boolean-parser". At the same level as my project, I see a file called "node_modules", which contains "boolean-parser".

I'm not sure if this is the right method of referring to the library... 
I'm also not sure how to find out what it.

If possible, please explain terminology in your answer(s)-- I have limited background knowledge in this area, as this is essentially my first real web project!

Happy to include code upon request. Feel free to suggest tag additions!

P.S. Could it be a file path problem? Do I need to use something like Browserify?

P.P.S. If I include

```
<script src="node_modules/boolean-parser/index.js"></script>
```

then it seems like the library is working, but then I get an error from within it:

*index.js:295 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at index.js:295*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are making client side project. Here is related question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I assume the most straightforward solution is to include the file using script tags? If so, I've tried this, and I'm having trouble with the file path. Seems like the library is working but not a module within it, and maybe I shouldn't refer directly to the index file-- any suggestions here?

Comment: Which functions do you need ? Maybe you can just copy them straight to you page ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I could... I'd rather keep them as separate files. Using <script src="node_modules/boolean-parser/test/test.js"></script> as the path, I get the same "require is not defined" error! I'm just not sure which .js within the library I should be referring to... this is kinda a new question, so I might post it as such. Edit: Actually, I can't post a new question yet-- so any responses would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Okay, update: I think I've determined I need the index.js file-- but when referring to this, I get: _Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined_

Comment: Easiest way is: change 'module.exports' to 'window.module' in index.js. In your html page you can access this functions through window.module.<function_name>

Comment: Do you mean I should do this and still use script tags to reference the index file? I changed to: 

Window.module = {
  deduplicateOr: deduplicateOr,
  ...
}; 

I still get the same error:  _module is not defined_

Comment: Yes, you still need use script tag for index.js

Comment: Okay, I did that, still get the same error: _module is not defined_.

Comment: Check again your script tag

Comment: <script src="node_modules/boolean-parser/index.js"></script>? This seems correct, because now the error refers to module, which is in the index file.                       
I've included the entire function in the main file, for now, to avoid the error, but I'm still interested in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Listen, i created simple html page with 2 script tags. First contains src="index.js" which is in the same folder and edited as i said before. Second script tags is:

```
<script>
  console.log(window.module):
</script>
```

And everything works. Check yourself again.

Comment: Please be patient with me-- I'm not familiar with these languages yet. I get the same error if I add both script tags. <script src="node_modules/boolean-parser/index.js"> and </script>
<script>console.log(Window.module); </script>                                       A few questions: Is the purpose of the second one to check if Window.module exists? If so, I'm seeing 'undefined'. Should window be capitalized in all instances?